# What are integers $x$ and $n$ such as $ x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1 = n^2$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

What are the integer numbers $x$ such as $x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$ is the square of an integer?

$0$ and $-1$ are obvious answers, but how many are there?

Comment: $1$ doesn't work, it gives $5$, which isn't a square.

Comment: Sorry, I meant $-1$. I fix it within the text

Comment: $$x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1=(x^2)^2+2\cdot x^2\cdot\frac x2+\left(\frac x2\right)^2+2x^2\cdot1+1^2+2\cdot\frac x2\cdot1-\frac{5x^2}4$$

$$\implies4(x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1)=\left(2x^2+x+2\right)^2-5x^2$$

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Idea: Bound between known perfect squares.

For $ x \neq 0$, we have (expand and verify)
$$ ( x^2 + \frac{x}{2} ) ^ 2 < x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1 < (x^2 + \frac{x}{2} + 1)^2. $$

Hence, the only possibility for a perfect square is for $x$ to be odd, and the square is equal to $ ( x^2 + \frac{x}{2} + \frac{1}{2})^2$. This gives us (expand and simplify) $ \frac{1}{4} (-x^2 + 2x + 3) =0$, hence $x=-1, 3$.

Adding in $x=0$, we get 3 solutions.