# Diophantine equation $a^{2} = b^{4} + b^{3} + b^{2} + b + 1$

Tags: diophantine-equations, euclidean-domain

As title sugests, I want to solve this equation $a^{2} = b^{4} + b^{3} + b^{2} + b + 1$ for integers $a,b$.

Actually, the exercise just asks to show that $b=3$ and this is in the section of euclidian rings so I think that I should use some euclidian domain related with the integers such as $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ and use the usual complex norm. But I cannot figure out which norm will give me something like $a^{2} = b^{4} + b^{3} + b^{2} + b + 1$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [for which values of $n$, $1+n+n^{2}+n^{3}+n^{4}$ is a perfect square?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3823379/for-which-values-of-n-1nn2n3n4-is-a-perfect-square) - found using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24a%5E%7B2%7D%3Db%5E%7B4%7D%2Bb%5E%7B3%7D%2Bb%5E%7B2%7D%2Bb%2B1%24%2C%20OR%20content%3Aintegers&p=1). There's also other duplicate posts here, e.g., [Determining all the positive integers $n$ such that $n^4+n^3+n^2+n+1$ is a perfect square.](/q/1270599), as well as multiple AoPS threads, e.g., ...

Comment: Or https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/510292/integer-x-for-which-x4x3x2x1-is-perfect-square

Comment: (cont.) [Dipohantine equation](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h1739927p11307620), [equation](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h1981802p13776270), etc.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Determining all the positive integers $n$ such that $n^4+n^3+n^2+n+1$ is a perfect square.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1270599/determining-all-the-positive-integers-n-such-that-n4n3n2n1-is-a-perfe)